# Why Angular ViewState enum is using 3 bits for some enum values

Tags: angular, bitmask

I am looking at some Angular source code and trying to understand bitmask of states for ViewState enum

Some of the states are using 3 bits instead of 1 bit like it is done traditionally.

```
/**
 * Bitmask of states
 */
export const enum ViewState {
  BeforeFirstCheck = 1 << 0,
  FirstCheck = 1 << 1,
  Attached = 1 << 2,
  ChecksEnabled = 1 << 3,
  IsProjectedView = 1 << 4,
  CheckProjectedView = 1 << 5,
  CheckProjectedViews = 1 << 6,
  Destroyed = 1 << 7,

  // InitState Uses 3 bits
  InitState_Mask = 7 << 8,
  InitState_BeforeInit = 0 << 8,
  InitState_CallingOnInit = 1 << 8,
  InitState_CallingAfterContentInit = 2 << 8,
  InitState_CallingAfterViewInit = 3 << 8,
  InitState_AfterInit = 4 << 8,

  CatDetectChanges = Attached | ChecksEnabled,
  CatInit = BeforeFirstCheck | CatDetectChanges | InitState_BeforeInit
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/types.ts#L368

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "using 1 bit", none of these are 1 bit. The left hand side of the operator just a value. `3<<8` just means "take the binary representation of the number 3 (`11` in binary), and shift it 8 spots to the left (`1100000000` in binary which is 768 in decimal). You cant turn `1` in binary into `1100000000` with a shift. You need something with 2 ones to do that, i.e. `3`d = `11`b -> `1100000000`b. Or an easier way to think of it for some is " 3<<8 means take the number 3, and multiply it by 2^8",

Comment: Yeah I get that, I just don't understand why some states are composed of shifting '1' to the left but all InitState flags are using different way of shift.

Comment: Its like I said, there is no way to shift `1` to get `11000000`, there's no way to shift `1` to get `11100000`, you need to start with `11` and `111` respectively to do that. `11 = 3`. `111 = 7`. The real mystery to me is why they went with `4<<8` instead of just `1 << 9`